# How do I add a new contact to Empathy?

Tags: 11.04, empathy

So far I've discovered that I can open my chat list by clicking the mail icon and not the chat icon. However, wherever I click, I can't find a way to add a new buddy.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Mail icon = Messaging menu, you can add a new contact on Empathyś main maindow.

Comment: And *how* do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

- Click on your Empathy window to activate it.
- Hoover your mouse to the upper side of your screen toward the word "Empathy" next to the Ubuntu logo. The menu appears.
- Click on Chat > Add a contact.

There you go!

Answer (score 1):

These instructions is for Classic not Unity

- Click on your Empathy window to activate it. (as Agmenor had said)
- Then Click `Chat` Then `Add Contact`

Hope this helps!